# Using Euler's formula to derive addition identities

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $z=e^{ix}$ and $v=e^{iy}$, show that $z\cdot v$ and $\frac{z}{v}$ can be used to establish each of the following :

- $\cos(x+y) = \cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$
- $\cos(x-y) = \cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y)$
- $\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)$
- $\sin(x-y) = \sin(x)\cos(y)-\cos(x)\sin(y)$

Now, I've tried multiplying $z$ and $v$ where I end up with $e^{ix+iy}$. I then factor out an i and end up with $e^{i(x+y)}$. At this point I use Euler's formula ($e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$) and end up with $\cos(x+y)+i\sin(x+y)$. However, at this point I reach a roadblock and don't know what to do next.
Any sort of help or assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

HINT:
$$e^{i(x+y)}=e^{ix}\cdot e^{iy}=(\cos x+i\sin x)(\cos y+i\sin y)$$

$$\implies\cos(x+y)+i\sin(x+y)=\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y+i(\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y)$$

and $$\dfrac{\cos x+i\sin x}{\cos y+i\sin y}=\dfrac{(\cos x+i\sin x)(\cos y-i\sin y)}{\cos^2y+\sin^2y}=?$$

Comment: Thank you^ Pretty sure I know what to do now